# Match one word in a factor R

Tags: r

I have a data frame (df) with information on houses. One of the variables is the raw address for each house.  Data frame looks something like:

```
City        address         beds  .. price
San Diego   4 Main street    4        400000
San Diego   12 Castle Villas 3        250000
...
```

Some of the addresses (which I have encoded as a factor variable, but could be changed) contain the word "villas" (or "Villas"). I want to identify all of the house addresses which contain the word "villas", and assign those to something, and assign all other properties to something else. This is for use in a decision tree for estimating house price.

Currently I'm trying things like:

```
df$rawAddress <- factor(df$rawAddress, levels=c(levels(df$rawAddress), "Other"))
    villas <- list("villas", "Villas")
    df$rawAddress[! df$rawAddress %in% villas] <- "Other"
```

But this is checking if the whole address is equal to "villas", so is false for all entries.

Comment: Use `grepl` to get regular expression matching

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can make a combined word using `|` separate and use as `pattern (regex)`argument of `grepl` to search for presence of either of two words.

```
villas <- c("villas", "Villas")

df$IsVilla <- grepl(paste(villas, collapse = "|"), df$address)

df

#        City          address beds  price IsVilla
# 1 San Diego    4 Main street    4 400000   FALSE 
# 2 San Diego 12 Castle Villas    3 250000    TRUE
```

**Data:**

```
df <- read.table(text =
"City        address         beds   price
'San Diego'   '4 Main street'    4        400000
'San Diego'   '12 Castle Villas' 3        250000",
stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by @James, you can use `grepl()` and `mutate()`, under the `tidyverse` approach.

Example with `mtcars` data set:

```
require(tidyverse)

mtcars %>% 
  select(mpg) %>%
  rownames_to_column("car") %>%
  mutate(MazdaORNot = as.integer(grepl("Mazda", car))) %>% 
  head()

                car  mpg MazdaORNot
1         Mazda RX4 21.0          1
2     Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0          1
3        Datsun 710 22.8          0
4    Hornet 4 Drive 21.4          0
5 Hornet Sportabout 18.7          0
6           Valiant 18.1          0
```

Comment: @Gregor True and thank you for you comment. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you want this?

```
set.seed(465)
df <- data.frame(
  city=rep(sample(LETTERS[1:10], 5), 2),
  address=rep(sample(c("castle villas", "VIP Villas", "something", "nothing"),
                     5, replace=TRUE), 2),
  beds=sample(1:8, 10, replace=TRUE),
  price=signif(sample(1e5:5e5, 10, replace=TRUE), 2)
)

villas <- grep("villas", df$address, ignore.case = TRUE, value=TRUE)
df$is.villa <- ifelse(df$address %in% villas, 1, 0)

> df
   city       address beds  price is.villa
1     I    VIP Villas    5 270000        1
2     H castle villas    1 260000        1
3     J    VIP Villas    2 250000        1
4     D       nothing    6 410000        0
5     F       nothing    3 350000        0
6     I    VIP Villas    1 190000        1
7     H castle villas    4 140000        1
8     J    VIP Villas    1 480000        1
9     D       nothing    5 260000        0
10    F       nothing    5 490000        0
```

Comment: Similar but looking for address to just contain "villas" rather than equal "villas" entirely. This returns 0 for all obs